# android studio Galaxy Device Family (AVD)

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device, galaxy

is there a way of importing the most used Android devices (for example Galaxy family) to the Android Virtual Device Manager as by default there is only some Nexus stuff in there?

Or did you create the Galaxy family the manual way in terms of specifying screen size for each device, upload device frame etc.?

Thanx for your help,
Florian